# How to pass arguments as CLOB in mybatis while using oracle functions?

Tags: java, oracle, gis, mybatis, oracle-spatial

I'm trying to put a lengthy WKT (a long string about geographical info) into an oracle spatial function `SDO_GEOMETRY` to transform WKT into oracle geometry type using mybatis. There are no column in the database that stores the WKT, it is only used as a parameter in the said function. The java type of the item is `String`, when I try to put it in it would return error, saying String too long. This indicates that the string is not being turned into a CLOB. How do I do that?

I tried using this at the start of mybatis .xml file:

```
<resultMap type="example.Building" id="BaseResultMap">
        <result property="geom" column="geom" jdbcType="CLOB"
                javaType = "java.lang.String"  typeHandler ="example.Utils.OracleClobTypeHandler"/>
    </resultMap>
```

and I have an `OracleClobTypeHandler` class set up.

I also tried using `#{wkt,jdbcType=CLOB}` but that went nowhere.

EDIT: This is the `SetParameter` method in the `OracleClobTypeHandler`:

```
    @Override
    public void setParameter(PreparedStatement arg0, int arg1, Object arg2, JdbcType arg3) throws SQLException {
        CLOB clob = CLOB.getEmptyCLOB();
        clob.setString(1, (String) arg2);
        arg0.setClob(arg1, clob);
    }
```

Comment: Not answering your question directly but there is an Oracle function sdo_util.from_wktgeometry() that takes a WKT string and returns an sdo_geometry.

Comment: `<resultMap />` is irrelevant as it is used when mapping query result to Java object. Have you tried specifying `typeHandler` in the parameter reference e.g. `#{wkt,typeHandler=example.Utils.OracleClobTypeHandler}` ? BTW, if it's an inner class, it should be referenced as `example.Utils$OracleClobTypeHandler`. If it still does not work, please post the full stack trace.

Comment: @ave I tried what you said, and the stack trace is `org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: Could not set parameters for mapping: ParameterMapping{property='wkt', mode=IN, javaType=class java.lang.String, jdbcType=CLOB, numericScale=null, resultMapId='null', jdbcTypeName='null', expression='null'}. Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid empty lob operation.
; uncategorized SQLException; SQL state [99999]; error code [17098]; Invalid empty lob operation.; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid empty lob operation.`

Comment: @ave The problem solved, it is an error in the `TypeHandler`, I changed `oracle.sql.CLOB` to `java.sql.Clob` and made other changes and then it worked. You should post your comment as answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @John_Doe Glad to know that the problem is resolved! I have posted my comment as an answer, but feel free to post your findings as a new answer and accept it yourself if it can be more helpful. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<resultMap />` is irrelevant as it is used when mapping query result to Java object.
Try specifying typeHandler in the parameter reference. e.g.
`#{wkt,typeHandler=example.Utils.OracleClobTypeHandler}`

Note that if the type handler is an inner class of `Utils`, it has to be referenced as `example.Utils$OracleClobTypeHandler` instead.